# Add a dll to C# CodeDom

Tags: c#, sqlite, codedom

Hi i want to compile a code at runtime using CodeDom. The code to be compiled requires System.Data.SQLite.dll. I already put that dll into my Desktop. How do i compile the code?

```
_CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            _CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"C:\Users\RsTylecsTacy-\Desktop\System.Data.SQLite.dll");
```

The error was The Type System.Data.Common.DbConnection is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx says that System.Data.dll contains the missing type